# suggest .erb 'functions' in sublime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sublimetext3

I'm barely beginning to understand Ruby on Rails and there are a lots of things I don't get to remember correctly, so I wonder if there's a way to enable suggestion and autocomplete for functions in html.erb files.

Right now it suggest me things when I'm working on ruby files, but this is not the case in html.erb files so I make a mess each time I try to remember how to do something until I find that I'm looking for 'yield' or 'provide'... I know is not a big help but I would love if sublime could suggest me this when I type 'y' or 'p' between <% %> tags.

Answer (score 1):

there are a few packages you can check for sublime text 3 ,

https://github.com/matthewrobertson/ERB-Sublime-Snippets

https://github.com/CasperLaiTW/ERBAutocomplete

some convenience you can get are, just write

> `er` and tab which will print <%  %>
>
> `ep` and tab which will print <%= %>

Comment: I'm already using ERB-Sublime-Snippets [in fact is `pe` for printable tags], I'm going to give it a try to ERBAutocomplete.

Comment: there is not much out there for your requirement, maybe consider creating your own sublime plugin, or try atom, or just get used to writing complete code.

Answer (score 0):

If this is about the *autocomplete popup* not showing while typing, rather than completions not working when pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd>, you need add the scope to you `auto_complete_selector` setting. By default, Sublime Text shows this popup only when working in the `source` scope, even though you can force showing the popup when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. To change this, open your user preferences (Preferences > Settings User) and adjust the `auto_complete_selector` by adding the `text.html` scope (or the more limited `text.html.erb`).

Comment: It is working as supposed, my problem is that sublime is not suggesting ruby functions inside and html.erb file.